# Sorting dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I d like to ask you how to sort dictionary by keys...the task is:you have a string of words and you have to count how much words are there and how much times is there ...for example : Hi mom hi dad hi -> hi 3 mom 1 dad 1 ...this is where I ended with this code :

```
zoznam = {}
x= 1
string= input ("")
rozdel= string.split()
for i in range (len(rozdel)):
    x = rozdel.count(rozdel[i])    
    zoznam[rozdel[i]] = x
print zoznam
```

..but now I have to sort that dictionary by keys (words) by first letter ..from example before -> dad 1 hi 3 mom 1 ...thank you :)

Comment: Try to avoid the variable name 'string'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html):

```
for key in sorted(zoznam):
    print key, zoznam[key]
```

Comment: -0 because answer lacks a disclaimer about dictionaries being unordered.  This is a newbie style question.  It needs an answer targeted to that level of understanding.